# Change (0, 1] to (0, 1) without branching

Tags: performance, haskell, random, floating-point, branchless

I have a random number generator that outputs values from `(0, 1]`, but I need to give the output to a function that returns infinity at 0 or 1. How can I post-process the generated number to be in `(0, 1)` without any branches, as this is intended to execute on a GPU?

I suppose one way is to add a tiny constant and then take the value `mod 1`. In other words, generate from `(ɛ, 1 + ɛ]`, which gets turned into `[ɛ, 1)`. Is there a better way? What should the `ɛ` be?

Comment: What language is this implemented in?

Comment: What language are you using?  Copying and modifying (or at least reading and understanding) your current pseudorandom number generator is probably your best approach.

Comment: For my particular use I'm interested in something that can be used with Accelerate within Haskell. The random number generator is from Curand.

Comment: Multiply by (1 - ɛ).

Comment: That's good, but are you sure it won't cause the smallest value to become 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 1**

In Haskell, you can find `ɛ` by using [`floatRange`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:floatRange). The C++ portion below applies otherwise.

---

**Note:** The answer below was written before the OP expressed the answer should be for Haskell

You don't state the implementation language in the question, so I'm going to assume C++ here.

Take a look at  [`std::nextafter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter).

This will allow you to get the next possible value which you can add to the upper limit, which will result in your code acting as if it was inclusive.

As for the branching, you **could** overload the function to avoid the branch. However, this leads to code duplication.

I'd recommend allowing the branch and letting the compiler make such micro-optimizations unless you really need the performance and can provide a more specialised implementation than the standard one ([see Pascal Cuoq's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710816/change-0-1-to-0-1-without-branching#comment43834302_27710864)).

Comment: The last time I looked at an implementation of `nextafter` on x86-64, it had 3 chained conditional branches (probably to ensure that the various IEEE 754 flags received the correct values), so any solution that uses `nextafter` certainly isn't “branchless”, although one can make one's own branchless limited version.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Whilst this may well be the case, by using a standard library functions you get the best the library implementers could come up with. If you can come up with better, and the library is open source, I'd advise making a pull request with your improvements.

Comment: The implementation I was referring to: https://github.com/aosm/Libm/blob/master/Source/Intel/nextafter.s That version was open-source, but the latest version isn't. Anyway, for `nextafter` as for many floating-point functions, there are tremendous improvements that are only possible in context (here: the argument is between 0 and 1), and that are not appropriate for library functions that have to work in all cases. Also state-of-the-art compilers are completely unable to infer the intent and specialize the standard function for you.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Fair comment. Although this seems defunct now, since the OP has now stated Haskell as the target language.